# How to set UserAgent to desktop mode in any mobile browser?

Tags: android, user-agent, mobile-browser

Can we set `UserAgent` for any mobile browser like Mozilla, Crome, UC Browser etc.

I have gone through `WebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);`

But It is for webview, My issue is I need to set `UserAgent` to all installed browsers, Not `webview`.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like it would violate a lot of Android's sandboxing principles, so I'm going to have to go with not possible (unless the device is rooted perhaps). Chrome for Android already has this as a feature anyway.